# How Nodejs event loop process pool phase and check phase while handling thousands of incoming http requests

Tags: node.js, pool, event-loop, nodejs-server, setimmediate

Imagine my web application is so popular and my nodejs web server handles thousands of requests per second and each request callback call setImmediate(cb) and i don't think setImmediate callback get a chance to run because event loop not get a chance to go to (check phase) setImmediate callback because there are thousands of requests callbacks in pool phase in every second, Is it true ?
I am trying to stimulate like this

This is my client side javascript code i am sending 50 requests to server:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
    console.log(data + ' ' + i);
}
fetchData()
```

}

This is my server side javascript code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
let num = 0;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    num = num + 1;
    console.log(`the request number is: ${num}`);
    // for(let i = 1; i <= 20000; i++) {
    //     console.log(i)
    // }
    // fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/text.txt`, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    //     console.log(`${data} ${num}`)
    // })
    res.status(200).send('hello from the server');
    // setTimeout(() => console.log('hello i am from timeout ' + num), 0)
    setImmediate(() => {
        console.log('hello i am from setImmediate ' + num )
    })
    // process.nextTick(() => {
    //     console.log('hello i am from nextTick ' + num )
    // })
    
})
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server is listening')
})
```

Nodejs docs says when event loop enter the pool phase it executes all callbacks in callbackqueue and when callback queue empty it then move to checkphase and execute the callback of setImmediate but in my example i am sending 50 requests from frontend and there should be 50 request callbacks in pool phase so why it is not completing the all 50 request callbacks and then execute the callback of setImmediate instead it is completeing one request callback and execute the callback of setImmediate and then the second request callback and after that callback of setImmediate.
I attached the image of output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the understanding of how event loop works in nodejs in misunderstood by you. At every phase of event loop, there is something called as timer that is triggered when that particular event loop phase starts executing. Once the timer runs to zero, the execution at that phase is stopped and it is moved on to next phase - so that there is no starvation at for other phases.

I am just trying to give you a very vague example here.

1. Let's say pool phase execution is started
2. Nodejs starts a times lets say for 500ms
3. Event loop will automatically goes to next phase - either when all the tasks are completed in pool phase or 500ms is expired.
4. Now setImmediate is automatically executed.

One thing to remember is there is no starvation in nodejs event loop concept at all.

if the application is so famous, run node in each thread of your process. Give tasks to workers. Read about these concepts, it will help.